# Rearrange the array of objects so as to add the replies to particular parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of Objects. It has two properties - commentID and parentID. I want to arrange it in such a way that the comments having the parentID should appear as the reply of the main comment. There is no limit to the count of the replies.The nesting can go to any level.

The current angular version I am using is Angular9. I cannot edit or modify the response from API. I need to proccess this at the Angular end.

```
**Array I am getting from API** : [
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":1,
   "parentCommentId":null,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2
},
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":2,
   "parentCommentId":null,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2
},
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":3,
   "parentCommentId":1,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2
},
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":4,
   "parentCommentId":3,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2
}
]

**Array I need** : [
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":1,
   "parentCommentId":null,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2,
   "replies":[
      {
         "description":"Comment Creation",
         "id":3,
         "parentCommentId":1,
         "postId":1,
         "user_id":2,
         "replies":[
            {
               "description":"Comment Creation",
               "id":4,
               "parentCommentId":3,
               "postId":1,
               "user_id":2,
               "replies":[
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "description":"Comment Creation",
   "id":2,
   "parentCommentId":null,
   "postId":1,
   "user_id":2,
   "replies":[
      
   ]
}

]
```

Comment: This is actually not related to Angular, but rather a general Javascript topic on how to transform arrays.

Comment: What have you tried. Instead asking that you want this expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very helpful function on Google and with little modification it did its job.

```
const getNestedReplies = (topLevelComments, parentCommentId = null) => {
        const nestedComments = [];
        for (const i in topLevelComments) {
            if (topLevelComments[i].parentCommentId === parentCommentId) {
                const replies = getNestedReplies(topLevelComments, topLevelComments[i].id);
                if (replies.length) {
                  topLevelComments[i].replies = replies;
                }
                nestedComments.push(topLevelComments[i]);
            }
        }
        return nestedComments;
    };
```